# EditText clears before I use contents

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to implement a `WebSocket` client in `Android Studio`.

My code works fine but I'd like to clear the text boxes after the data has been set. When I tried to clear my `EditText` boxes after the 'SEND' button is clicked I found that they were being cleared before they were being used.

If I use the following code the contents of the text boxes gets sent,

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        start  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        client = new OkHttpClient();
        add    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_str);
        cmd    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cmd_str);
        key    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.key_str);
        data   = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.data_str);

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                start();
            }
        });
    }
```

But if I use the following...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    start  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
    client = new OkHttpClient();
    add    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_str);
    cmd    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cmd_str);
    key    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.key_str);
    data   = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.data_str);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            start();
            add.getText().clear();
            cmd.getText().clear();
            key.getText().clear();
            data.getText().clear();
        }
    });
}
```

I just get an empty string sent. How do I stop this? I have tried setting a sent flag that is only set after the text has been sent...

```
start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        start();
        if (sent){
            add.getText().clear();
            cmd.getText().clear();
            key.getText().clear();
            data.getText().clear(); 
            sent = false; 
        }
    }
});
```

...but the text never gets cleared.

**Edit #1:** Full MainActivity listing

```
package qdivision.org.websocketexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.WebSocket;
import okhttp3.WebSocketListener;
import okio.ByteString;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button start;
    private TextView output;
    private OkHttpClient client;

    public EditText add;
    public EditText cmd;
    public EditText key;
    public EditText data;

    public boolean sent = false;


    private final class EchoWebSocketListener extends WebSocketListener {
        private static final int NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000;

        @Override
        public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {

            String addStr    = add.getText().toString();
            String cmdStr    = cmd.getText().toString();
            String keyStr    = key.getText().toString();
            String dataStr   = data.getText().toString();
            String dataFrame = "<" + addStr + "," + cmdStr + "," + keyStr + "," + dataStr + ">";
            webSocket.send(dataFrame);

            webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, "Goodbye !");
            sent = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
            output("Receiving : " + text);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
            output("Receiving bytes : " + bytes.hex());
        }

        @Override
        public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
            webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null);
            //output("Closing : " + code + " / " + reason);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {
            output("Error : " + t.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        start  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        client = new OkHttpClient();
        add    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_str);
        cmd    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cmd_str);
        key    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.key_str);
        data   = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.data_str);

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                start();
                /*add.getText().clear();
                cmd.getText().clear();
                key.getText().clear();
                data.getText().clear();*/
            }
        });
    }

    private void start() {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("ws://192.168.1.84:81/").build(); //"ws://echo.websocket.org"
        EchoWebSocketListener listener = new EchoWebSocketListener();
        WebSocket ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);

        client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
    }

    private void output(final String txt) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                output.setText(output.getText().toString() + "\n\n" + txt);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your start() method

Comment: you can store the values of editext in string variables and pass those variables as parameters of start method after that just clear your editexts

Comment: @JaskaranSingh have added full` MainActivity` code (which also annoyingly finishes after one send)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, about the `sent flag`. If you are using another thread for settings its value, does not mean, this thread has to wait for it to read the value. In the `if statement`, if it is not true, it will skip the body. So, as soon as `start()` is called, assuming that `start()` is running on another thread, this thread will read the next statement and skip the loop.
Try using something like an `OnCompleteListener()` provided with the API that you are using.
The same logic goes with the `editText.getText().clear()`. If you are trying to read the text in `start()` after any HTTP call, the program will not wait for it and execute the remaining statements.
Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Since onOpen happens asynchronously, the values that you're trying to pass are already cleared by that time. The simplest way would be to assign the values from your EditTexts to variables and then read them in onOpen. You could also add a constructor to your Websocket implementation that accepts String as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

```
data.setText("");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
editText.getText().clear();
```

will clear the text box.